# Are "self" and "root" different when creating buttons in a Python Class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, frame

In the script below button_01 and button_02 are created in "self" and "root" respectively. Is there any functional difference where they are created? The GUI looks the same either way.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        frame1 = tk.Frame(root, padx=2, pady=2, borderwidth=2, relief="raised")
        frame1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        button_01 = tk.Button(self, text ="tk Button 1") # self with tk.Button
        button_01.config(width=15, fg="black", bg="lightskyblue")
        button_01.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        button_02 = tk.Button(root, text ="tk Button 2") # root with tk.Button
        button_02.config(width=15, fg="black", bg="lime")
        button_02.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        button_03 = tk.Button(frame1, text ="tk Button 3") # frame1 with tk.Button
        button_03.config(width=15, fg="black", bg="lightcoral")
        button_03.pack(side=tk.TOP)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
#
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `self` and `root` are not the same. Widgets live in a tree-like hierarchy, with a single root. When you call `tk.Tk()` you are creating this root window.

`self` represents the object to which the methods belong. In this case the widget is a subclass of `tk.Frame` which is a child of `root`.

Try giving the frame a background color (eg: `self.configure(background="red")` and you will see that the buttons have different parents. The gui looks the same in this specific example whether you use `root` or `self` only because it is an extremely simple gui with a very simple layout.

Comment: I took your suggestion and added:
        self.configure(background="red")
        root.configure(background="green")
        frame1.configure(background="blue")
That makes it clear there are three different areas in the GUI.